# How to sum up multiple datasets [0, 1, 2, 3, 4...] with always data [0] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, chart.js, dataset

I am still a rookie and need some help.

There is my variable chartdata as starting point:

```
var chartdata = {
  labels: [
    "Bar 1",
    "Bar 2",
    "Bar 3",
    "Bar 4",
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Green data",
      type: "bar",
      data: [20, 30, 40, 20]
    },
    {
      label: "Red data",
      type: "bar",
      data: [10, 30, 20, 10]
    },
    {
      label: "Blue data",
      type: "bar",
      data: [20, 20, 20, 20]
    },
```

As I have a stacked barchart. I want to know how I can **sum** the "Bar 1" datapoints which are 20, 10, 20 = 50.

I first thought about an array and it was like this:

```
const array0 = chartdata.datasets[0].data;

console.log(array0.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
```

...but it could only add 20 + 30 + 40 + 20, which is all the data within dataset[0] and similar operations. Means I can only get all Green datapoints or others. Not the total sum for one stacked bar.

It did not seem possible to make something like chartdata.datasets[0 to 4].data[always 0]; which is the tota l val"bar 1" value on the y-axis.

I tried to set up something with .map, but I could not really do it on my own.

Maybe you, experts, can provide me a solution which I can directly run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#reduce` over `chartdata.datasets` itself.

```js
let chartdata={labels:["Bar 1","Bar 2","Bar 3","Bar 4",],datasets:[{label:"Green data",type:"bar",data:[20,30,40,20]},{label:"Red data",type:"bar",data:[10,30,20,10]},{label:"Blue data",type:"bar",data:[20,20,20,20]},]};
let res = chartdata.datasets.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.data[0], 0);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is working completely fine thank you a lot Unimitgated! As said I am a rookie and I thankful people assist me to a certain point. 

So how can I then automize that a function runs through all my bars. finds the max stacked bar and then displays it in the console.log .

Cause I just to this in order to get the max value of the stacked bar for optimizing my max scale value.